# CSS class not working in dynamically added select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am dynamically adding select box on button onclick by jQuery. But CSS class for the select box not working.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var max_fields = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
    var x = 1;
    $("#addMore").click(function (e) {
        $(".selectized").addClass("data-md-selectize data-md-selectize-bottom");
        e.preventDefault();
        if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(".more_field").append('<div class="uk-width-large-1-4 uk-width-medium-1-2 abc"  data-uk-grid-margin><div>Railway Station(s)</div><div> </div><select id="select_demo_2" class="selectized" data-md-selectize data-md-selectize-bottom><option value="a">Ambikapur</option><option value="b">Baloda Bazar</option><option value="c">Bhatapara</option><option value="d">Bilaspur</option><option value="e">Champa</option><option value="f">Dalli-Rajhara</option><option value="g">Dhamtari</option><option value="h">Dongargarh</option><option value="i">Durg-Bhilainagar</option><option value="j">Jagdalpur</option></select></div><div class="uk-width-large-1-4 uk-width-medium-1-2"><div>&nbsp; </div><div> &nbsp;</div><select id="select_demo_3" class="selectized" data-md-selectize data-md-selectize-bottom><option value="">Select...</option><option value="a">Agra Cantt. Railway Station (AGC)</option><option value="b">Agra Fort Railway Station (AF)</option></select></div><div class="uk-width-large-1-4 uk-width-medium-1-2"><div> &nbsp;</div><input type="text" class="md-input validate[required]" name="student_username" id="ereq1" placeholder="Distance"/></div><div class="uk-width-large-1-4 uk-width-medium-1-2"><div><div class="uk-form-row"></div></div></div><a href="#" onclick="calcTotal()" class="remove_field uk-icon-remove"></a></div>');
        }
        $(".more_field").on("click", ".remove_field", function (e) { //user click on remove text
            //alert('test');
            $(this).parent('.abc').remove();
            x--;
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: You are binding a click event within a click event.

Comment: I didn't understand.. I am appending div on button onclick event

Comment: I don't think this is causing your issue but you also have an extra closing div within your appended html. This will cause you problems too.

Comment: Which css class isn't working? Can we see the css?

Comment: I am using this theme : altair.tzdthemes.com and ''data-md-selectize data-md-selectize-bottom'' this is the class which is not working when dynamically added in select box.. otherwise its working fine.

Comment: If you look at your code, you'll see you close off the class statement before you add those two classes:  class="selectized" data-md-selectize data-md-selectize-bottom you need to change it to class="selected data-md-selectize data-md-selectize-bottom"

Comment: Still not working.. :( I can see in the view source that class is there but its not working

Comment: can you post relevant html too??

Comment: http://pastebin.com/uviTxFUt

Answer (score 0):

You are closing the class after adding only one attribute:

```
 <select id="select_demo_3" class="selectized" data-md-selectize data-md-selectize-bottom>
```

You need to change it to include all three that you want to be applied:

```
 <select id="select_demo_3" class="selectized data-md-selectize data-md-selectize-bottom">
```

You have the same issue on both select boxes.

Also you need to update it on your top div from:

```
<div class="uk-width-large-1-4 uk-width-medium-1-2 abc" data-uk-grid-margin>
```

to

```
<div class="uk-width-large-1-4 uk-width-medium-1-2 abc data-um-grid-margin">
```

Comment: yes.. have you checked this theme... altair.tzdthemes.com